# How to handle wide columns with \backslashbox?

Tags: tables

I'm using the package `slashbox` and my left column is reasonably wide, how can I tune the diagonal line (created by `\backslashbox`) such that it starts and ends in the corners of the cell?

Example code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{slashbox}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\begin{document}
 \begin{table}[ht!]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ *{4}{|c}|} 
   \hline
   \backslashbox{foo}{bar} & test & header & header \\
   \hline
   relatively wide column& b & $3$ & $4$ \\
   ds & c & $1$ & $4$ \\
   \hline
  \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest and most straightforward way of doing this is to specify the literal size of the slashed box.  In your case, it's about 40mm.  So try this:

```
\backslashbox[40mm]{foo}{bar}
```

Generalising this approach would not be much more complicated. Compute the size of the backslashbox by taking the size of the column's widest string then add on two times the width of the table's column separators.

[image]

Comment: +1 for this simple solution. ALthough it increases the column with. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: yes, nice answer to the question. Too bad there isn't a more automatic way to achieve this. Now I have a dilemma, @Thorsten answer offers a visually better way to solve this, but this answer by @Geoffrey is the exact answer to the question asked, which should I accept?

Answer (score 6):

Since this is an issue concerning the [slashbox](http://ctan.org/pkg/slashbox) package itself, the only solution might be a hack of the package source. Consider to restructure the table and tweak it with the [booktabs](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package. See code below for some ideas.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf,tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{Table caption}\label{tab:default}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{|c}|}\hline
      \multirow{2}{*}{foo} & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{bar} \\ \cline{2-4}
       & test & header & header \\ \hline
      relatively wide column& b & $3$ & $4$ \\
      ds & c & $1$ & $4$ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}

  \begin{table}[!ht]
    \caption{Table caption}\label{tab:booktabs}
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{4}{c}}\toprule
      \multirow{2}{*}[-0.5ex]{foo} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{bar} \\ \cmidrule{2-4}
       & test & header & header \\ \midrule
      relatively wide column& b & $3$ & $4$ \\
      ds & c & $1$ & $4$ \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

It is also worth to think about dropping vertical lines to improve legibility of the tables as shown above.

Comment: yes, the actual table does not have vertical lines, but I included them to make the point about the diagonal line. and I was already using booktabs, but I just reduced the problem for the example, but I like the second suggestion, I hadn't thought about that.